# Using Fluent NHibernate with NHibernate 3.3

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have just seen that NHibernate 3.3 is out and I have tried implementing it in a fresh project.

Much like with version 3.2 I have run into issues with using Fluent NHibernate, I have added version Fluent NHibernate version 1.3 and am getting the following error message.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.2.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

Can I get fluent safely running with the latest version of NHibernate? I know previously building the FluentNHibernate source against NHibernate could work. Is this recommended or have things changed significantly enough in 3.3 to make issues likely?

I have checked the Fluent NHibernate site and I can't see much recent activity. Does anyone know if James is planning on continuing supporting Fluent I know he had some doubts.

http://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2011/04/13/me-on-nhibernate-3-2/

Really do hope support continues as NHibernate's mapping by code just does not feel as intuitive and there is still not much information out there on it.

Cheers

Steve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get the [latest sources](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate) and compile it against the latest NHibernate. As long as NHibernate doesn't change something in the XML configuration schema, this will always work. I'm already using it that way without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, points to you for getting in there first :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here.

1. Put [assembly redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (You can try to do it with Nuget command [Add-BindingRedirect](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference)
2. Compile from source code

Answer (score 2):

To answer the second part of your question...

James posted this to the FNH Google Group on Jan 27, 2012:

> Hey everyone,
>
> I've noticed people are starting to get a bit restless around here. I
>   suppose you all deserve a bit of an explanation.
>
> Fluent NHibernate is not dead; however, it is severely neglected. The
>   reasons I'll go into in a moment, but I don't intend on letting the
>   project die; it may just have to remain in its neglected state for a
>   while longer. The pull requests are occasionally being dealt with, but
>   it's only me here now and I just simply don't have the time to deal
>   with it.
>
> Help would be appreciated, but I don't expect it. If anyone wants to,
>   get in touch (james @ jagregory.com); I'm more interested in project
>   management help than code right now, as we're still fairly active on
>   that front (contributors, that is).
>
> There isn't really a roadmap at this point in time, due to lack of
>   activity; but I've always planned on getting a 1.3/4 release out then
>   pushing on to a cleaner-tighter 2.0 release; when that'll happen is
>   anyone's guess right now.
>
> Personal stuff: feel free to skip if you've heard enough. So the
>   reason for all this slacking is that I've quit my job in London,
>   relocated to Australia, and joined ThoughtWorks in Sydney (and now
>   temporarily in Melbourne). It's a big move, quite literally halfway
>   around the world. I'm having to reestablish myself over here and
>   that's a very time consuming experience; new country, new job, new
>   city, new friends, etc... My priorities have shifted entirely away
>   from non-essential projects and once the day is over, the last thing I
>   want to do is boot up the VM and crank out some code. I hate to
>   dissapoint people, and I hate to neglect FNH, but my priorities have
>   (temporarily) changed.
>
> Hope that at least clarifies what some people are thinking. Feel free
>   to ask any questions and I'll do my best to actually answer.
>
> Cheers, James
>
> P.S. Mailing list messages - sorry about that. Google Groups
>   apparently decided to stop notifying me of new messages. All
>   outstanding ones have been approved.

I offered to help with some of the admin work, but after a couple of email exchanges with him, did not hear anything further.

Comment: Glad he hasn't let it die, guess we just need to be patient. Virtually all the guys working with NHibernate I know are using fluent. Would be a real loss to the community if we lost it. Cheers Tom.

Comment: Some good news - I see James made a bunch of GitHub updates yesterday, including updating to NH 3.3.

Comment: did you hear anything new on this? the last activity was on Oct 2012 and there are already 17 pullrequests unhandled

Comment: Afraid not. I'm seriously considering replacing FNH with RavenDB in my project - mainly because a document store is probably a better fit for the problem domain - but lack of support for FNH is a factor too.